# Most efficient way to calculate the distance between 2 integer coordinate points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two tridimensional coordinates stored as six `int` values. 
What is the more efficient way of calculating the `float` distance between the described locations:

1. `Vector3.distance( new Vector3( (float) a, (float) b, (float) c), new Vector3 ( (float) x, (float) y, (float) z)) ;`
2. Implement the proper math in a function taking the integers as parameters and doing all casts to float, all ^2, and the square root in plain c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1: There's a function for that in Unity: [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html), as you already added. This is the most efficient way (the only better option would be to get float values instead of ints at the first place).
 #2: 
`//unity
private Vector3 Int2Vector3 (int x, int y, int z) {
     return new Vector3 ((float)Mathf.Sqrt(x), (float)Math.Sqrt(y), (float)Math.Sqrt(z));
}
//plain c#
private float Int2FloatSqrt (int a) {
     return (float)Math.Sqrt(a);
}`
**EDIT**: Here's Unity's .Distance function for a better understand:
`public static float Distance(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    Vector3 vector = new Vector3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
    return Mathf.Sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y + vector.z * vector.z);
}`

Comment: I added [Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html), the best way if you are only manipulating `X` and `Y`